# Generate R Markdown report using VBScript

Tags: r, vbscript, r-markdown

Is there a way to generate an R Markdown report by calling that or other R scripts in a VBScript on windows 7?

My goal is for the user to be able to click the VBScript and have the R Markdown file generate so that the user does not have to interact with R.

I am able to run an R script  from a VBScript (using Rscript.exe), but when it comes to an R Markdown file, there seems to be an issue with knitting/rendering. 
I am able to source the R Markdown file from an R Script and I also used an R script to generate the HTML report using Markdown functions (see [here](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/render-reports-directly-from-R-scripts/)), but if I call either of those from a VBScript, the report is not generated. I know the script is running because I also generate a text file (outside of the R Markdown file) as a test.

B/c I lack Admin rights, I don't believe I can use a batch file, but regardless, I think I would encounter the same issue. Thanks for any help/insight!